# <a> Tag not lining up with <img>

Tags: html, css

I have some really basic HTML and CSS and for some reason the outline of the link is lower than the image itself, but they should line up because the image is inside the  tag as below:

[image: Image taken from Firebug overlay]

The code for this is:

```
<div id="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/deviantart.png" alt="DeviantArt"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/flickr.png" alt="Flickr"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/google+.png" alt="Google+"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/social/youtube.png" alt="You Tube"/></a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#social {
  float:left;
  width:24px;
}

#social a {
  padding:0px;
  height:24px;
}
```

Has anyone got any idea why they are not in line and if so how to get them in line?

Comment: It is because images are rendered differently on the baseline. You could set the `img` tag to have `display: block;` or perhaps `display: inline-block;`, or play around with `vertical-align` on the image tag.

Comment: You re missing the inline block for the element covering your link tags

Comment: Putting display: inline-block; on all the elements seemed to do the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `display:inline-block;`

```
#social {
  float:left;
  width:24px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```